# Grep error due to expanding variables with spaces

Tags: bash, grep, double, quotes, variable-expansion

I have a file called "`physics 1b.sh`". In bash, if I try

```
x="physics 1b"
grep "string" "$x".sh
```

grep complains:

```
grep:  physics 1b: No such file or directory.
```

However, when I do

```
grep "string" physics\ 1b.sh
```

It works fine. So I guess the problem is something to do with the variable not being expanded to include the backslash that grep needs to recognize the space. How do I get this to work?

Using bash 3.2, mac os 10.6.

Edit:
Never mind, the problem was that x was set to `" physics 1b"`, but when I did  `echo $x`  to check the contents, bash chopped off the spaces in the front so I couldn't tell that it was different. The first way above actually works.

Comment: Note that there is a space in front of '` physics 1b`' in the error from grep; are you sure it didn't mention .sh on the end of the file name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the entire argument in double-quotes:

```
grep "string" "$x.sh"
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, even without the edit to the question, though it is often the best way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

use this in your script.

```
grep "string" "${x}.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
grep "string" "${x}.sh"
```